# Programming unlisted ST microcontroller

Tags: stm32, microchip, programmer

STM32F400CBT6 is not found in the list of ST microcontroller. I've bought it from LCSC. It's datasheet is found in LCSC only that is also in Chinese only. I am not able to program it using stlink.
The schematic I used to program is as shown.
How can I program it? When I try to program it, the stlink programmmer does not detect the ic. Have I done something wrong it the schematic or this ic need another way to program?

[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: If an MCU does not exist, how do you think any programmer hardware or software can program it? It is likely a fake/clone chip. Also that schematic has many errors if it is assumed to be a STM32 MCU. So the result is as expected, it won't work.

Comment: @Justme  Maybe explaining the errors would help. It seems to be a genuine ST part, as one would expect from LCSC.

Comment: Is it your schematic? You miss some VDD/VSS pins, that may explain why the MCU is not responding to your STLink.

Comment: The errors are too numerous to list in details. Better look at STM32 datasheet, reference manual, and hardware design guides to know how to design it so that it works, because this MCU has also built-in core voltage regulator that can be disabled to use an external one.

Comment: May I know the reason behind connecting all the VDD/VSS pins although they are internally connected?

Comment: @rs04 Why do you assume they are internally connected? Are you sure they really are?

Comment: Checking through multimeter, I found continuity between all VDD pins and VSS pins.

Comment: @rs04 What does that mean? How did you measue it? Is there continuity of 100 ohms or 1 ohms? And then you still left VDDA and VSSA pins, VBAT, VCAP disconnected. If you want it working, better do as the documetation says.

Comment: I am not convinced it is an actual ST part. I have heard recently of fake ST parts with ST markings being sold by ST. They are clones. I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's listed on ST's [Chinese website](https://www.stmcu.com.cn/Product/pro_detail/STM32F400CBT6/view_detail/entity/stm32f4/pn/STM32F400CBT6). But not in English. I guess they're doing market segmentation.

Some questions in their forums about building a project suggested building for a  STM32F410CB but I don't think that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> May I know the reason behind connecting all the VDD/VSS pins although they are internally connected?

The internal connections not only have "continuity" but also have parasitic series impedances that a simple multimeter won't help you measure.

The fact that there are internal connections is an implementation detail. You must operate as if those connections weren't there. Otherwise you can damage the chip, or make it misbehave. Never skip any power nor ground pins - they must **all** be appropriately connected!!